# Como conectar una BD en la Nube a traves de Mysql Administrator?

Tags: mysql

Que tal espero puedan ayudarme, y espero no cancelen este post por falta de código, pero quisiera saber por que no me conecta a mi BD en la nube.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la primera imagen la conexión es exitosa (workbench) y en la segunda no (mysql administrator)

Comment: Has revisado esta entrada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376109/mysql-workbench-incompatible-nonstandard-server

Comment: Gracias, la acabo de revisar, aunque no logro resolver lo que necesito, pero creo que la pregunta va orientada a otra cosa, necesito generar backup automatico y he usado mucho mysql administrator para eso, pero esta vez no lo puedo hacer, ya lo hice con una tarea CRON pero como lo deja en algun lado del servidor que no tengo acceso no me sirve.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión del servidor?

Comment: es la version 5.0.20 @Sal